# Ubuntu 18.04 USB mouse does not work after boot from a powered off state: can't read configurations, error -71

Tags: dual-boot, usb, 18.04, mouse

I have a newly installed version of Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted with Windows 10.  Setup went great and I've had no issues using Ubuntu.  However, when I turn on my computer and boot into Linux, my mouse pointer will not move.  I have a mouse that lights up when it is powered on and when it is not working I noticed the lights are off.  It seems that it isn't even getting power when this happens.  To fix this, I just turn the computer off and back on again then the mouse has power and everything is fine. When I boot into Windows 10, the mouse always works. It has become a common enough occurrence that I have power cycle again, after turning it on initially, on a daily basis just to get the mouse working.

I have a Razor Naga USB mouse.  The keyboard (also USB) doesn't seem to be effected.  The mouse is using the USB in the back of the computer (as opposed to a USB hub or additional port on the keyboard).

Has anyone had this issue?  How would I even go about troubleshooting this?  I'm not familiar with investigating system level failures (like USB drivers for example) in Linux.

**Update: dmesg output:**

```
[    1.792881] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    1.797053] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=0012
[    1.797054] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.797055] usb 1-8: Product: USB Audio Device
[    1.797056] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.
[    1.928008] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.061261] [drm] failed to retrieve link info, disabling eDP
[    2.064752] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20171023 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    2.077201] usb 1-9: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[    2.077203] usb 1-9: can't read configurations, error -71
[    2.204069] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    2.256394] checking generic (d1000000 300000) vs hw (b0000000 10000000)
[    2.256447] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb1: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.354338] usb 1-9: string descriptor 0 read error: -71
[    2.354342] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=001f
[    2.354343] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.355456] usb 1-9: can't set config #1, error -71
[    2.480295] usb 1-14: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    2.629969] usb 1-14: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=021e
[    2.629984] usb 1-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.629985] usb 1-14: Product: Razer Ornata Chroma
[    2.629986] usb 1-14: Manufacturer: Razer
```

After I disconnect and reconnect the mouse:

```
[ 1436.941950] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1446.504530] usb 1-9: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 1446.654938] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=001f
[ 1446.654941] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1446.654944] usb 1-9: Product: Razer Naga Epic
[ 1446.654946] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: Razer
[ 1446.656777] input: Razer Razer Naga Epic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:1532:001F.0006/input/input28
[ 1446.657065] hid-generic 0003:1532:001F.0006: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Razer Razer Naga Epic] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input0
[ 1446.657984] input: Razer Razer Naga Epic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.1/0003:1532:001F.0007/input/input29
[ 1446.716997] hid-generic 0003:1532:001F.0007: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Razer Razer Naga Epic] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input1
```

Using this command:

```
strings /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h
```

I found what error code -71 is: `EPROTO     71  /* Protocol error */`

But I still don't know what this really means... and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This removes the mouse. If you run the above command by mistake, run this: `sudo modprobe -a psmouse`

Comment: and what happens after running that cmd?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using a Razer Diamondback 2 mouse on openSUSE Tumbleweed and was able to fix it. I've included a description on how I solved the problem below, since I'm not using Ubuntu and as the problem seems to be very hardware specific.

**tl;dr:** Add the line following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist mt76x2u
```

**How to make sure the solution works for you**:

It seems to be a problem with a MediaTek's *mt76x2u* firmware driver. Loading the driver seems to result in a page fault if the Razer device is plugged into USB 3 (at least that's what happened to my mouse and keyboard).

You should probably make sure first that you've got the same problem. `dmesg | grep mt76x2u` got me several lines, including these two:

```
[   10.367973] mt76x2u 5-4.2:1.0: firmware upload timed out
[   15.552552] mt76x2u: probe of 5-4.2:1.0 failed with error -5
```

You should also see similar errors in `journalctl`.

Once you've made sure that you have the same problem, you just need to disable the driver. It was recently added to linux-firmware, and everything worked fine for me before, so I concluded that I just don't need it.
Find your *modprobe blacklist*. For me it's `/etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf`, but appearently its `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` on some other distributions. Then blacklist the kernel module by entering the line `blacklist mt76x2u`, save and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It appears I do not have the same problem that you have, but I was able to find the info in dmesg that describes what is going on.  I've updated my question with the information.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the problem and found this thread before trying anything. Didn't actually read until after fixing.

Here's how it went: Logitech G600 mouse clearly indicating power from lights. Same with keyboard. Keyboard responsive. Brought up mouse settings, didn't tell me anything. Both are connected to KVM switch. Unplugged mouse and plugged it back in. Instant cure!

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
64-bit
GNOME version 42.4
Linux 5.15.0-47-generic

Answer (score -1):

you can try this  : sudo modprobe -r psmouse

Comment: How does removing the mouse module help?

Answer (score -1):

this works for me

change in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=0"
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

then shutdown and restart

Comment: Isn't "synaptics" the mousepad on a laptop?  I'm not using a laptop, this is a desktop with only the USB mouse, no touchpad.